# Kibana Filter to detect exceptions in Java Application logs

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-dsl, kibana-7, elasticsearch-watcher

I am trying to write a ELK-Watcher to send alert in case of any exception in my Java-Application logs.

Our application-log is already getting indexed in Elastic-Search. And under ***`log_message`*** field, I am able to index log-message or exception-message(in case of exception) along with exception-trace.

For example

In normal case(with no exception) ***log_message*** field will have value something like as follows.

```
Executing task using ExecutorService
```

But in case of Exception, ***log_message*** field have something like as follows

```
Exception while executing task : java.util.concurrent.CancellationException [StackTrace Hash 38fe72fbd18c26e8cd74b0a3c196c1441f1814e10224a323f83ec105dd355f10]
java.util.concurrent.CancellationException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:121)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at com.comp.tasks.TaskExecutor$MDCFuture.get(TaskExecutor.java:103)
        at com.comp.tasks.TaskExecutor.afterExecute(TaskExecutor.java:239)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Above two are just sample **log_message's**, but exception can originate from any other class in application with different exception-message or exception-trace.

I want to write ELK-Watcher and use **Kibana-filter-query-DSL** to detect if **log_message** field contains exceptions.

I tried many different Kibana-filter-query-dsl to filter-out ***log_message*** with exception trace. But none of them worked.

Is it possible to write any Kibana-filter-query-dsl to detect exception by looking for ***\n\tat*** in  **log_message** field? Please help.

Comment: are you storing `log.level` field from your application log ? If you are storing then it will be very easy because then you need to just check if `log.level` value is `error` and send alert.

Comment: I am using log.level, but the problem is log.level=ERROR used for many other cases and not alone for Exception case.

Comment: ok got it. then you can try out to search for `StackTrace` or `at java.lang.Thread.run` which will be available for all your stacktrace. You might get some unexpected result but most of scenario it will cover.

Comment: Ok, I tried following, it works fine but it is very slow, I am doing search only for 15 min duration, but numbers of log lines generated by application in 15 min are very high( around 60K), and takes 3-4 minutes to provide result. Any solution to improve the performance of following query?

{ "bool": { "must": { "wildcard": { "log_message": { "value": "\*at java.lang.Thread.run\*" } } }, "filter": [ { "term": { "severity": "ERROR" } } ] } }

Comment: Your are trying `wildcard` query with prefix and postfix `*` thats why it is taking long time. Insted of this try `match_phrase` query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out to search for `StackTrace` or `at java.lang.Thread.run` which will be available for all your stacktrace. You might get some unexpected result but most of scenario it will cover.

Below is query you can try:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "message": "at java.lang.Thread.run"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "severity": "ERROR"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why but match_phrase does not work me,